# How do I execute php code within a variable containing html

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I assembled a Wordpress shortcode but it throws an error in the block editor: "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response." Notwithstanding, the edits are saved. I've been told the reason I get the error is my "shortcode handler function is generating output. Such functions must collect all output into a variable which is returned."

Below are (1) the code that works but causes the error message and (2) my pseudo code to fix the problem by assigning the 'a href' to a variable $html, but doesn't.

(1)

```
function make_header() {
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category_name' => 'headlines',
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args);

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();        
    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div><img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" width="100%" /></div>
    <h2>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </h2></a>
<?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
}
add_shortcode('make_header', 'make_header');
```

(2)

```
$html = '
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <div><img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" width="100%" /></div>
    <h2>
    <?php
        the_title(); ?> </h2></a>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $html;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's look like you need to use concatenation operator why inside php you are using php tag still not understand. just suggestions may be im wrong.

Comment: I did try using concatenation and substituting them with variables such as $p=the_permalink() and $t=the_title() and ended up with the URL and the title printing on the screen together and the href pointing back to the page rather than the post.

`$p=the_permalink();
$t=the_title();
$html = '
<a href="'.$p.'">
    <div><img src="'.$featured_img_url.'" width="100%" /></div>
 <h2>'.$t.' </h2></a>';

    }
 return $html;`

Comment: it look like you get the answer. keep coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could to use concatenation like so:

```
$html = '<a href="' . esc_url(get_the_permalink()) . '">';
$html .= '<div>';
$html .= '<img src="' . $featured_img_url . '" width="100%" />';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2></a>';
```

Also, use `get_the_permalink()` and `get_the_title()` as these functions are returning their result instead of outputting it.

The full code would then look something like this:

```
function make_header() {
    $html = '';
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'category_name' => 'headlines',
    );
    $q = new WP_Query( $args);
    
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();
            $featured_img_url = esc_url(get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'));

            $html = '<a href="' . esc_url(get_the_permalink()) . '">';
            $html .= '<div>';
            $html .= '<img src="' . $featured_img_url . '" width="100%" />';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2></a>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('make_header', 'make_header');
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion re get_the_permalink and the title. That immediately solved the error message. I prefer your style of concatenation so I'll use it instead. I did think of it and thought it would complicate my head. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$html = ' <a href="'.the_permalink() .'"> <div><img src="'. echo $featured_img_url .'" width="100%" /></div> <h2>'. the_title().' </h2></a>';
```

the concatenation operator (‘.‘), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments.